# SSDT will not publish assembly

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to publish a custom assembly with SSDT, but the assembly and related stored procs are not getting picked up and deployed.  Schema compare is not yielding any result either.  The assembly and procs do not exist on the target database and SQLCLR is enabled.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Comment: Within Visual Studio, check the properties of the assembly file(s) and the stored procedure files and make sure they are included in the build.  There are some other properties that need to be checked for assemblies.

Comment: The cs files are set to compile and the procs are set to build. I recreated the project and manually copied the files to the new project. The new project deploys the assembly and the props match between projects. The old project worked without issue for >1 yr. there were no recent changes that I am aware of, but our svn history is only kept 90 days for some awful reason. Still I haven't made changes to the files in a long time so the only change would have been to the version of ssdt used, but that does not explain how the new project worked. --Thanks for the reply

Comment: Here's a post to look at that I've used to troubleshoot similar issues with deploying Assemblies and CLR procs. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63028/reference-assembly-in-sqlproj-not-being-deployed-to-server

Comment: Thanks. This refers to a referenced assembly. In my case, I have clr stored procs for our own custom assembly. The only properties to set our in the project properties. Generate ddl is set to true which is the only thing that appears relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I found that doing a REBUILD on the project seemed to fix the problem.